# UIWebView passing username and password into a form

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview, passwords

I have a UIWebView set up containing my universitys intranet page, my code will pass in my username fine (as it is a number)

```
NSString *studentNumber = @"639909";
NSString *javaScriptNumber = @"document.getElementById('username').value=%@;";
javaScriptNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat: javaScriptNumber, studentNumber];
[webViewInt stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: javaScriptNumber];
```

However when i try to run the same code to fill in the password field, it will only work with numbers, my password is text so when I enter text nothing will pass into the password field. However if I set my password to be all numbers it seems to work. Is there something in this code I need to change to allow it to pass all characters as it currently only passes numbers

Thankyou

(This is the code for the password)

```
  NSString *password = @"password";
NSString *javaScriptPass = @"document.getElementById('password').value=%@;";
javaScriptPass = [NSString stringWithFormat: javaScriptPass, password];
[webViewInt stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScriptPass];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you change this:

```
NSString *javaScriptPass = @"document.getElementById('password').value=%@;";
```

to this:

```
NSString *javaScriptPass = @"document.getElementById('password').value='%@';";
```

it should work. Notice that I added single quotes around `%@`.

Numbers worked because the JavaScript interpreted the password you entered as a number; however, when you put a string in there with no quotes, it's tries to run you password like it's part of the code instead of as a string. You should probably add the quotes for the student number field too, since you are really using the number as a string.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much. And thank you for the explanation, JavaScript seems to be my mortal enemy at the moment.